# Issue with interface and parameter

Tags: java, parameters, interface

I have problem with interface and parameters:

```
public class Functions {
  public static Double getInfoSum(TreeMap<String, Iinterface> map){
    ....some counting
  }
}

public class ExampleClass {

  private TreeMap<String, ExampleClassItem > xxxx;

  public static void SomeFunction(){
    Functions.getInfoSum(xxxx); //HERE IS ERROR 
  }
}


public class ExampleClassItem implements Iinterface {

  .....

}
```

Is there any other possibility except do this:

```
private TreeMap<String, ExampleClassItem > xxxx; -----> private TreeMap<String, Iinterface > xxxx;
```

because I need to work with `ExampleClassItem` there are specific functions which can be not in Interface.

Comment: Try to double cast: Functions.getInfoSum((TreeMap<String, Iinterface>)(TreeMap)xxxx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change

```
public static Double getInfoSum(TreeMap<String, Iinterface> map){
 ....some counting
}
```

to

```
public static Double getInfoSum(TreeMap<String, ? extends Iinterface> map){
 ....some counting
}
```

This will allow you to pass a `TreeMap<String, ExampleClassItem>` to this method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
 public static void SomeFunction(){
   Functions.getInfoSum(xxxx); //HERE IS ERROR 
 }
```

Your "xxxx" is not static, and your method is static so you can't use non static fields inside your method.

You can change your method and use "?" wildcard

```
public static Double getInfoSum(TreeMap<String, ? extends Iinterface> map){
```

So you can pass here anything that extends Iinterface.

ExampleClassItem is subtype of Iinterface
but `TreeMap<String, ExampleClassItem>`

is not subtype of `TreeMap<String, Iinterface>`